# Move computer accounts to new OU in bulk

Tags: active-directory

I have an OU with around 2500 computers. I need to move 580 of them to another OU. Is there a way to do this with a batch file? I have a text file with the computernames (not the FQDN).

Answer (score 9):

```
FOR /f %%i in (C:\path\to\textfile.txt) do (

  dsquery computer -name %%i | dsmove -newparent OU=newOU,DC=domain,DC=com

)
```

That should take care of it for you.

edit: It's been a while since I've had to use dsmove :) It needs the DN of the object that you're moving, so I added the dsquery in front of a pipe to get the DN from the list and then pipe it to dsmove. This should work fine now for a list of just NetBIOS names.

Comment: +1 for doing it in 1 command

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the names of your comptuers in a text file and 1 on each line youc an run the following command to export the fqdn of them

```
FOR /f %%a in (file.txt) DO dsquery computer -name %%a >> fqdnfile.txt
```

Then run the following command to move them. Please use the echo command in lue of dsmove to test this first

```
FOR /f %%b in (fqdnfile.txt) DO dsmove %%b -newparent OU=newOU,DC=domain,DC=local
```

Test it out. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't need the FQDN for dsmove afaik.

Comment: Sweet, never actually needed to move things in bulk before. But I've read much about the command. Good to know! Glad I got close to the same answer you did :)

Comment: I had to dig into my old batch scripts :) I've moved a lot of this type of thing to PowerShell now.

Comment: I'm not a scripting goeroe :(.

Comment: I get this ... PS C:\Users\kva> FOR /f %%a in (c:\xp.txt) to dsquery computer -name %%a > c:\fqdnfile.txt
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
At line:1 char:5
+ FOR  <<<< /f %%a in (c:\xp.txt) to dsquery computer -name %%a > c:\fqdnfile.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (OpenParenToken:TokenId) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword

Comment: @Grey Tux You should run the script in `cmd` not `powershell`.

Comment: okay. used cmd and get this C:\Users\kva>FOR /f %%a in (c:\xp.txt) to dsquery computer -name %%a > c:\fqdnfile.txt
%%a was unexpected at this time.

Comment: it must be %a instead of %%a

Comment: Yeah, two % is if you're running it from a batch file. One % is if you're running it from the command line

Comment: Okay. It's helping :).

I use this syntax in cmd -> FOR /f %G in (c:\xp.txt) do dsquery computer -name %G > c:\fqdn.txt

Works fine but ...... I only see the last entry of xp.txt in fqdn.txt. Seems that I overwrite.

Grey

Comment: change the > before fqdnfile.txt to >>

Comment: @greytux - if you use powershell (and the quest tools) it's much simpler and faster: get-content textfile.txt | foreach-object -process {move-qadobject –identity $_ –newparentcontainer (get-qadcomputer –service “mydomain.com” other_pc_in_the_sameOU).parentcontainer  If you happen to know the destination you can use that instead of looking it up

Answer (score 1):

A small error in Nixphoe's answer -- `to` vs `do` and a missing `do`

```
FOR /f %%a in (file.txt) do dsquery computer -name %%a >> fqdnfile.txt

FOR /f %%b in (fqdnfile.txt) do dsmove %%b -newparent OU=newOU,DC=domain,DC=local
```

Comment: Welome to ServerFault.  Please feel free to [make suggested edits to existing posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work). These suggestions will be vetted by the community for approval.

Answer (score 0):

Little step by step for new admins:
Get file.txt where computer names are listed there one per line.

```
PC-001
PC-002
PC-003
```

Open CMD and make sure your line is indicating to be at the same location as your file.txt then paste the line below

```
FOR /f %a in (file.txt) DO dsquery computer -name %a >> fqdnfile.txt
```

This will create a file fqdnfile.txt in the same location as your file.txt

This will parse fqdnfile.txt with Distinguish names (one per line)

NOTE: that you should use double %% for BAT file and single % for CMD

Then run the line below.

```
FOR /f %b in (fqdnfile.txt) DO dsmove %b -newparent "OU=COMPUTERS,OU=My Bus,DC=Domain,DC=com"
```

NOTE: Your distinguish name should be enclosed in "" if you have spaces in names, e.g. My Bus

RUN the line below to check if everything was moved correctly

```
FOR /f %a in (file.txt) DO dsquery computer -name %a >> location.txt
```